# How to get rid of the trailing html tags in ckeditor in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I'm working on a timed project and can't seem to get rid of the html tags in my views after a user enters rich text...

I have searched this forum several times for an answer to this problem but non has helped. Example...

```
<div class="kh"> <p> This is a test content...I&#39;m trying to get rid of the trailing html codes.&nbsp;</p> <p> &nbsp;</p> <p> <strong>See this??</strong></p> </div> <p> &nbsp;</p>
```

I cannot remove the html tags. Can someone tip me on a work around?

Some code from my views: (_form.html.erb)

```
<%= f.cktext_area :more_meaning, :height => 150, :swf_params => { :assetable_type => 'Test', :assetable_id => 1 } %>
```

and (index.html.erb) `<%= tech_term.more_meaning %>`

Cheers!

Comment: Which tags do you want to remove? The final `<p> &nbsp;</p>`?

Comment: I want to get rid of all tags on displaying the text. Simple_format and raw on (<%= tech_term.more_meaning %>) will only remove all tags and leave me with plain text. I want to see that formatted text intended by the user displayed...bold, italic, paragraph etc...

Comment: The solution to this problem might be the same as the one asked in [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981170/wmd-editor-rails-compass-how-to-get-the-generated-markdown-code-read-as-htm/9252797#9252797

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem for this which might do the trick for you. Have a look at the gem here https://github.com/hgimenez/truncate_html.

It is a good idea to use it because sometime simple_format or raw truncate your description without closing a tag.

For example if you have a  `<b>` tag and your have given the truncate length at 500 and your `</b>` comes after 500 then your whole layout will go for a toss. On the other hand truncate_html will look for the closing `</b>` before truncating it so it is kind of context aware.

Comment: This didn't quite do what I wanted, but thanks for your response. I have decided to go for WMD-editor and it looks promising...